# obtaining id of an html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to obtain postdata from a form and send it 
  via ajax .
     The code is given below :

```
var $fields = $('#myform :input').serializeArray();
var values = {} 
jQuery.each($fields, function(i, field)
{

                   values[field.name]  = field.value

 });
 myJson = JSON.stringify(values);
```

Now, instead of `values[field.name]` I want id of the element to be
key of postadata to be sent . I have tried `values[$(this).attr('id')] = field.value` but,
It is not working .     Any help will be valuable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
    var values = {};
    $("#myform :input").each(function(i, field) {
          values[field.id] = field.value;

    });

    var str = (JSON.stringify(values));
```

Answer (score 1):

insted of this

```
var $fields = $('#myform :input').serializeArray();
```

do this

```
var $fields = $('#myform :input').map(function(){
   return {'id': this.id, 'value': this.value}
}).get();
```

and be careful with the `$` on `$fields` variable.

Answer (score 0):

also you could do this

```
var values = {} 
$('#myform :input').each(index){
   values[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).attr('id')
}
 myJson = JSON.stringify(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't serialize the Array. I'd guess you delete the properties of the dom-elements that way.

Try using instead:

```
var values = new Array(); 

//this way you'll get an array of DOM-elements with all their properties
jQuery('#myform :input').each(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this); //I do this to make the later code more readable, can be omitted

    values[$this.attr('id')] = $this.val();
});
```